# Adding an amount to a certain array index in Java

Tags: arrays

I'm working on a project where I need to create 20 different circles with increasing brightness of red as the loop goes. I'm trying to find a way to increase the red value in an RGB style array here's my code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < circles.length; i++)
  {
    int[] gradient = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
    circles[i].changeColor(gradient);
    System.out.println(circles[i]);
    gradient[0] += 15;
```

For some reason the shade of red is not increasing. I try adding 15 to the the 0 index of the gradient array (the 0 index is the red in the RGB) and it doesn't increase. I'm thinking it has something to do with how I'm adding the value to the array. Does anyone know what's going wrong and how can I fix it?

BTW, don't worry about the changeColor method, that's an existing and working method in a class on the program.

Answer (score 0):

By declaring the gradient variable inside the 'for' loop you are setting it back to 0,0,0 each iteration. Make the declaration prior to the loop and you should be fine.

```
int[] gradient = new int[]{0, 0, 0};

for(int i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    circles[i].changeColor(gradient);
    System.out.println(circles[i]);
    gradient[0] += 15;
}
```

Comment: Can I see the output? Would be useful to see the value of gradient at the same point you are seeing the circle.